# Conditional check if user is logged in Umbraco

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, conditional-statements, umbraco, roles

How can i check if user is logged in to umbraco from the view(.cshtml)?

I would also know how to check the users role.

`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` always returns false.

```
if( User has role = "someRole" )  
{  
    do stuff
}
```

Im using Umbraco version: 7.8.1

Comment: Are we talking about a frontend user (member) or a backend user (user)?

Comment: Im new to writing questions in stackoverflow. So when i wrote the if statementi didn't know it would look like that. i didn't mean to write User as a type, just as plain text for explaining. we are talking about backend user thats logged in. But the if statement is placed front end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if user is logged on, Not Member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476810/how-to-check-if-user-is-logged-on-not-member)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this code to be working for my application:

```
var auth = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current).GetUmbracoAuthTicket();  

if (auth != null)
  { <p>Name: @auth.Name</p>
    <p>ID: @auth.UserData</p>
  }
```

Resource :  ["Umbraco.Web.UmbracoContext.Current.Security.CurrentUser" returns "null" for front-end requests](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-6496)

Comment: Be aware, the code is checking if the current user is logged in to the umbraco backend and only then you'll get to see the output in the frontend of the website. Is this what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: Actually, yes :)

Answer (score 1):

If `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false you are probably not calling `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);` after the user is successfully validated.

To check the authentication and roles use:

```
var userIsAuthenticated = Request.IsAuthenticated;
var userIsAdmin = User.IsInRole(role: "admin");
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if an Umbraco user is logged in on front-end, I'm using this:

```
var isLoggedInUmbraco = userTicket.GetUmbracoAuthTicket()!=null;
//To add a Umbraco edit link on a page:
if(isLoggedInUmbraco){
<a href="/umbraco/#/content/content/edit/@Model.Content.Id">Edit Page</a>
}
```